# Verifying Linear Regression implementation using python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I just started with machine learning, spent few hours learning Linear Regression. Based on my understanding I implemented it from scratch in python (code below) without regularisation. Is my logic correct or does it need any improvements?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Assigning X and y from the dataset
data = np.loadtxt('ex1data1.txt', delimiter=',')
rows=(data.size)/2
X = np.array((data[:, 0])).reshape(rows, 1)
y = np.array(data[:, 1]).reshape(rows, 1)
m = np.size(X)
X = np.insert(X, 0, values=1, axis=1)
t = np.ones(shape=[2, 1])

def linReg():
   h = np.dot(X,t)
   J = 1/(2*m) * sum((h - y)**2)
   print('Cost:',J)
   print("Error:",h-y)
   for i in range(1,2000):
       h = np.dot(X,t)
       t[0] = t[0] - 0.01*(1/m)*(np.dot((X[:,0]),(h-y)))
       t[1] = t[1] - 0.01*(1/m)*(np.dot((X[:,1]),(h-y)))
       J = 1/(2*m) * sum((h - y)**2)
       print(i)
       print('Cost:', J)

   plt.scatter(X[:,1],y,color= 'blue')
   plt.plot(X[:,1],h)
   return t

def predict(newval):
  W = linReg()
  predValue = np.dot(newval,W[1]) + W[0]
  print("Predicted Value:-",predValue)
  plt.plot(newval, predValue)
  plt.scatter(newval, predValue, color='red')
  plt.xlim(0, 40)
  plt.ylim(0, 40)
  plt.show()

print("Enter the number to be predicted:-")
nv = input()
nv = float(nv)
predict(nv)
```

Answer (score 0):

To check your model, a simple thing to do would be to *split your data into a training set and a test set*. The training set is used to *fit the model*, by being passed as an argument to the `linReg` function, and the features of the test set are used for *prediction* (with your so-called `predict` function).

You will then need a third function to *score* your model, by *comparing the predictions with the actual values given by the data*. If you get a good score, then your implementation may be correct, and if not, a little debugging will be necessary ;-)

To get started, I would suggest rearranging your code by defining the following functions:

```
def train_test_split(X, y):
    """
    Return a splitted version (X_train, y_train) and (X_test, y_test) of the dataset.
    """

def linReg_train(X_train, y_train):
    """
    Fit the model and return the weights.
    """

def linReg_pred(X_test)
    """
    Use the fitted model to predict values for all the points in X_test.
    """

def linReg_score(y_predicted, y_test)
    """
    Compare predicted and true outputs to assess model quality.
    """
```

Some resources you might find useful:

- [A friendly introduction to linear regression with Python](http://www.dataschool.io/linear-regression-in-python/): a series of videos that goes into detail about how to implement linear regression.
- [Linear regression in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html): scikit-learn is one of the most useful libraries for machine learning in Python, with a very well-written documentation. If you plan to write your own implementations of ML algorithms, you may want to check them  by running your data through the scikit-learn implementations and compare the outputs with those of your own work.

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll try that.